# Thread Ids, & identification

Tags: cuda

I have few doubts for thread numbering and threadIDs.

1. 2D-Thread(1,0) is thread 1, as its x index is 1 and y index is 0. Then comes thread(0,1) what is the thread id or thread number of this thread? I feel it is 3, but how? How can we apply formula of ThreadId =  blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x for thread(0,1)? How can I use this formula to compute, threadID value for thread(0,1) for say block 3? Or there is different formula, how to find?how to do for 3D?
2. How can we determine total no. of threads in x direction together?
   For example: if i am accessing matrix elements. Matrix size is 3, then i understood that thread(0,0) will access 1st element, thread(1,0) will access 2nd element, thread(2,0) will access 3rd element, then thread(0,1) will access 1st element of 2nd row(4th element).
   But how thread(3,0) is neglected from this picture? Which element thread(3,0) will access and how? 
   It depends on the execution configuration, where i have given block size and grid size?

Comment: See "2.2 Thread Hierarchy" in the CUDA C Programming guide.

Comment: One question per question please: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @PaulR. Oh ok. Sure. I will put 1 question per question.

Answer (score 2):

The threadIdx is a struct with .x, .y and .z fields. Writing it as "thread(x,y)" can be confusing.

1. You're creating a 2D thread block and trying to map it to a 1D index. Of course you can *do* that, but the 2D to 1D mapping will depend on the context of your application. Most people would use 1D if they actually want a 1D index!

   Of course, you may well need to take a 2D thread index and access a linear array, but again the layout of the array will be application-dependent. A typical example would be something like `offset = threadIdx.y * arraywidth + threadIdx.x`.
2. The total number of threads in the x direction is `gridDim.x * blockDim.x`.

   Which element is accessed by a given thread depends on how you choose to compute the offset (see (1)).

Talonmies also pointed you to the [Thread Hierarchy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) section of the docs, a good place to start.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and I will surely go through the Thread Hierarchy section pointed by Talonmies.
1)But, actually, still I am not cleared with the concept. Actually, I am not trying to do 2D over 1D mapping. Rather I want to know what will be the thread ID(thread value of thread number) for thread (0,1)?
2)
2a)Also, all the elements will be placed linearly in the memory, whether I am accessing using 1D, 2D or 3D thread blocks.
2b)If total elements in 'x' direction is gridDim.x*blockDim.x, then for 2D thread blocks, what is the total no. of threads in 'y' direction?Should I sum them?

Comment: @robot: FOr (1) if you want a linear thread ID, then why are you using a 2D block/grid? Just use a 1D system and be done with it. Check out the vectorAdd example. For (2b) the total threads in each dimension uses the same formula `gridDim.P*blockDim.P` where P is {x,y,z}.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I read in the text book, that each thread in 1D or 2D have unique thread ID, eg: if it is 1D then I can compute the value using blockIdx*blockDimx + threadIdx; eg: total 10 threads/block thread 0 of block1 will have thread ID = 10*0+0 = 0 and thread0 of block 1 will have threadId = 10*1+0 = 10. This is for 1D. I am asking if the case is for 2D threads, then how to find unique thread ID?

Comment: Yes, every thread in a 2D block will also have a unique thread ID, but the unique thread ID is a two-dimensional value, i.e. it has two components x and y! Of course you can linearise a 2D or 3D coordinate, but how you do that is up to you as the programmer. The programming model simply gives you a unique 1D, 2D or 3D ID according to the grid/block shape.

Comment: @   Tom   : Thanks for making me understand the concepts. Thank you